# How to write bash script in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I am currently learning bash script on MacOS with the default zsh shell.
I have tried to use the bash syntax `read -p`,  but it returns `-p: no coprocess`. I would like to ask: can I use bash syntax when writing bash in zsh? Since I find the zsh style `read` work even with the line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` added in the beginning,

inside the testSpace.sh file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ts() {
    source ~/.local/bin/testSpace.sh
}

zshread () {
    read "?type some input: "
    echo $REPLY
}

bashread () {
    read -p "type some input: "
    echo $REPLY
}
```

output in shell:

```
 ~/.local/bin $ source testSpace.sh
 ~/.local/bin $ zshread
type some input: ttt
ttt
 ~/.local/bin $ bashread
bashread:read:1: -p: no coprocess
ttt
 ~/.local/bin $
```

Comment: You are not doing what you think you are. You are not running the function in bash, you are sourcing the functions into your current shell -- which is zsh -- which is why the `-p` option is interpreted as coprocess. If you want to run a bash shell, run (don't source) with bash, e.g. `bash myscript.sh` -- then the `#!....` will be honored.

Comment: The two shells have much in common, but the only straightforward way to write portable shell script is avoiding features which are specific to either of these shells, i.e. basically restrict yourself to strict POSIX `sh`. Then your script will be runnable with plain `sh`, too. In the limit, this is like asking how you can run Fortran code in Python, or understand Chinese when you only understand English.

Comment: Target bash, or zsh. Only the most trivial sh-compatible scripts have a chance of running on both. They're just too different.

Comment: Correction: `bash myscript.sh` ignores the shebang, and runs it in bash (which in this case is the same thing, but not always). To have it respect the shebang, make the script executable (`chmode +x testSpace.sh`) and then run it directly with `./testSpace.sh`.

Comment: Your question sounds a bit like ".... Can I use Basic syntax in Java?". Why using zsh if you are not willing learning the language? Since bash and zsh share some similarities, you will learn zsh faster than a completely different language, but still read the manuals and learn the constructs. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1474343/resources-to-ease-transitioning-from-bash-to-zsh#1575416) link will help you in the transition.

Answer (score 2):

The shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is not necessary in this situation. When you run a script or binary file, the `exec()` command executes the file specified after the [shebang](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/shebang/8thedition_exec.2.html). However, if you explicitly specify an interpreter in the command line, the shebang will be ignored.

You can read more about how shebang works [here](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/shebang/index.html).

In this particular case, making the file executable and running it as a script will not produce the intended result because using the zsh's `source` built-in command will force the use of the zsh interpreter, which will ignore the shebang.

If you need to execute a function in zsh using bash, you can run bash and pass your script after the `-c` option.

```bash
bashread () {
  bash -c '
    read -p "type some input: "
    echo $REPLY
  '
}
```

Next, in the zsh interpreter,`source` the functions.sh file. Now, when `bashread` function is called, bash is executed and the `read -p "type some input: "` line is interpreted by bash.
It is also possible to check the process executable file by inserting the line `readlink -e /proc/$$/exe` into the function.

```
bashread () {
    readlink /proc/$$/exe
    bash -c '
    readlink /proc/$$/exe
    read -p "type some input: "
    echo $REPLY
    '
}
```

The output of this example function:

```
$ bashread                                                                                                                                                                        
/usr/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/bash
type some input: test
test
$
```

Take note that bash code is single quoted '...' to prevent zsh interpreter expansions.